# Which is the best navigation method to manage stack in react-native?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, react-native, react-router

I have used few react native navigations and I am still confused for which one to use so that future perspectives are also managed. I have used [react-navigation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation) which is default by react-native and [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux), also I have used [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) which has a very good documentation. But so many options confuse me. Please help as my project is a bit large project and I don't want to switch navigation technology in between.

Comment: you need to define your requirements first,as to what kind of an app do you require,is it going to be a page to page hierarchy or something like a Tab view or Navigation menu etc

Comment: It's a mixed one. Login then Home screen which has navigation drawer. then there are tab views and bottom sheets.

Answer (score 3):

I've used both [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) and [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) in my projects and experienced their behaviour on large and normal sized apps.

Overall, they are both native-based navigation libraries with easy to integrate redux support. When it comes to a large project having more count of screens with more populated content, I would recommend [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation). In the docs, it says:

> React Native Navigation provides 100% native platform navigation on
>   both iOS and Android for React Native apps.

It means that it will provide a 100% native user experience in terms on navigation. [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) also uses react-navigation in the background but when you examine the source codes, you'll see that there is more JavaScript connection between native and react-native sides. It's implemented to have one more layer between for a simplified usage and it works good on normal-size projects. But as the size gets larger, it will cause slower performance; because instead of directly calling native actions, it will first go to JavaScript bridge it. So it depends on you to determine the tradeoff between simple usage and performance.

Answer (score 1):

I use [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) navigation for my react-native projects, my these is some issue , but its the best you can find, and with v2 they fixed a lot of issues , and it's recommended by react native, lately i tried [react native navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/) its 100% native navigation with a cross-platform interface, it worth to take a look, but i did not used it in a real project, so for now i recommend you react-navigation.

Comment: Hi, is it easy to migrate to v2 ? is it stable ?

Comment: yeah it's pretty easy to migrate it depends on your navigation's complexity

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple navigators that you can choose from. Below are some of the navigators that were officially included in React Native’s documentation.

**NavigatorIOS** is a wrapper around UINavigationController, allowing you to implement a navigation stack. It works in the same way as it would on a native app using UINavigationController, providing the same animations and behaviour from the UIKit.
To set up the navigator, provide the initialRoute prop with a route object. A route object is used to describe each scene that your app navigates to. initialRoute represents the first route in your navigator.

**Navigator** Unlike NavigatorIOS, Navigator works for both iOS as well as Android. Navigator is just the JavaScript implementation of NavigatorIOS.

**NavigationExperimental** was intended as the replacement for Navigator. But due to lack of documentation, it was soon abandoned as well. Another drawback here was that NavigationExperimental did not have any pre-defined actions. You had to write your own actions.

**Ex-Navigation** is another navigator that uses NavigatorExperimental’s API internally. Here, the use case was easier and pre-defined functions were also introduced.

**React Native Router Flux** is built on top of NavigationExperimental and used by many developers. It is also quite easy to understand, its backed by a strong community. The only drawback is defining various routes can get complex sometimes.

**React Navigation** was created because there was a need for an extensible but easy to use navigation method, React Navigation can be used in React as well as React Native projects, allowing for a higher degree of shared code.

**React Native Navigation** is one of the best navigation libraries available. It provides a completely native platform navigation on iOS and Android for React Native apps. The JavaScript API here is very simple and cross-platform.React Native Navigation comes with optional redux support.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, we had react-native-router-flux for navigation before 8 months, but we faced so many issues with it, while navigating to another component.

Thoguh we had implemented react-navigation for routing, then we acheived **tab animation** and **smooth routing between the pages**, controlling the over the component rendering from bottom to top and vice verse along with preventing unneccessary routing between the pages.

I prefer: react-navigation.